# How to fix Minimum and Maximum crop size for an Image in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

How I can fix image minimum size while cropping (Zooming Out)
Technology: Android

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
1. subclass Transformation and implement your crop logic
2. subclass one of the transformations you've mentioned and apply your logic

Comment: I tried with above mentioned 3 crop transformations but not succeeded. @MarkySmarky How about bitmap scale?

Comment: Bitmap scaling is done with Picasso pretty easily - you can specify the target width/height when you fetch the image.